# using psql with inline sql as command parameter that includes double and single quotes

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, psql

In my Jenkinsfile I need to update postgresql. The final sql is supposed to be like;

`UPDATE "Common"."VersionInfo" SET "Api"='dev-475';`

I need to use double quotes for casing and single quotes for string value.
I created avariable for sql;

`updateSql = "UPDATE \"Common\".\"VersionInfo\" SET \"Api\"=\'${appVersion}\';"`

And use it in sh commannd like this;

`sh "PGPASSWORD=${NPASS} PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF-8 psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=ON -h ${postgresDbIp} -p 5432 -d ${postgresDbName} -U ${NUSER} -1 -c '${updateSql}'"`

However, Jenkins pipeline throws error;

```
ERROR:  column "dev" does not exist
09:27:56  LINE 1: UPDATE "Common"."VersionInfo" SET "Api"=dev-475;
```

How to preserve both double and single quotes here?
Thanks

Comment: Another good example why using quoted identifiers [should be avoided](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)

Comment: The easiest solution is to put the SQL statements into a file and use `psql ... -f file_name.sql` or use a [heredoc](https://linuxhint.com/bash-heredoc-tutorial/)

Comment: I've created a shell file and pass parameters from within my jenkinsfile to this shell script. Although I did not want to add a separate file, it seems the most logical solution.